# Multiple Selectors not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont unterstand why this is not working.
The b's just bounce with the setInterval Function, but not on hover...

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#b2, #b3, #b4, #b5, #b6').hover(function(){
                $(this).effect("bounce", {times: 1}, "slow");
            });

        setInterval(function() {
                    $("#b2").delay(2000).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
                    $("#b4").delay(4000).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
                    $("#b6").delay(6000).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
                    $("#b3").delay(8000).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
                    $("#b5").delay(10000).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
                }, 1000);     

        });
```

Comment: `effect is not a function` BTW. Could you please make a jsfiddle or codepen or something? I cannot guess what happens within your `effect` function.

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code. effect is jquery-ui function, not jquery. You can get more information about effect method [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/effect/)

```js
$('#b2, #b3, #b4, #b5, #b6').hover(function(){

setInterval(function() {
    $("#b2").delay(2000).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
    $("#b3").delay(4000).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
    $("#b4").delay(6000).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
    $("#b5").delay(8000).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
    $("#b6").delay(10000).effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow");
}, 1000);     



})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="b2">div2</div>
<div id="b3">div3</div>
<div id="b4">div4</div>
<div id="b5">div5</div>
<div id="b6">div6</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue your code was ok you need to include jquery UI lib. in your code. I hope it will help you..

Load Jquery file first then jquery-ui into your html code...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js[enter link description here][1]"></script>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/e99m0kqq/2/) is working jsfiddle example